# how to position two divs above each over

Tags: css, html

Is there any way to start drawing divs from the same point? That means if I add new div and then I add another div, they will appear above each other. Because I want to move them all together depending on the same point.

CSS:

```
#num1,#num2{
    display : inline
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='num1'></div>
    <div id='num2'></div>
</div>
```

So what should I add to this code so when the browser render this code the 2 divs will be on the same place?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

All statements regarding absolute positioning are correct.  People failed to mention, however, that you need **position: relative** on the parent container.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#num1,
#num2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='num1'>1</div>
  <div id='num2'>2</div>
</div>
```

Depending on which element you want on top, you can apply **z-index**es to your absolutely positioned divs.  A higher z-index gives the element more importance, placing it on the top of the other elements:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#num1,
#num2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
/* num2 will be on top of num1 */
#num1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
#num2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='num1'>1</div>
  <div id='num2'>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I do is make the divs different colors, and then make one a different size so can tell which one is on top. Then I change it back to what I need it to be.

Comment: @tahdhaze09: if you are dealing with only two absolutely positioned divs you'd only need to change one background-color.  If you see the color, it's clearly on top :-P

Comment: @Laith - Common practice on Stack Overflow is to accept the most correct and complete answer as correct if it fixes your issue or answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use z-index to position divs on top of one another:

[http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp][1]

So, you'll position the divs with absolute/relative positioning and then use z-index to layer them:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Please make answers self-contained. This description is not very helpful without reading the linked webpages - which may disappear or change over time.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first one position:absolute, which should take it out of the normal flow of the page.

[some help](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is to use absolute positioning

Answer (score -1):

You can use absolute positioning.

```
  #num1,#num2{ display : inline position:absolute; left:50px;top:10px; }
```