# Part of div isn't showing

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, which one is a sticker with price and other is an image of product. Unfortunately some part of price sticker is cut off:

[image: Cutted sticker]

And i want something like this:

[image: Price sticker]

html

```
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
    <div class="product-grid third">
    <div class="product limited text-center">
       <div class="tag-price-home">
          <div class="price"><span>R$</span><br>10.0</div>
       </div>
       <a href="/produto/prod-kelly-01-1">
       </a>
       <div itemscope="" itemprop="itemListElement" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
          <a href="/produto/prod-kelly-01-1">
             <input type="hidden" id="produto_id" value="1">
             <meta itemprop="sku" content="1">
          </a>
          <div class="product-img"><a href="/produto/prod-kelly-01-1">
             </a><a href="/produto/prod-kelly-01-1">
             <i class=""></i>
             <img src="/fotos/1508954963747_mini.png" alt="Prod Kelly 01" title="Prod Kelly 01">
             </a>
          </div>
          <!-- /.product-img -->
          <div class="product-price" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
             <meta itemprop="sku" content="1">
             <meta itemprop="availability" content="http://schema.org/InStock">
             <meta itemprop="itemCondition" content="Disponível">
             <meta itemprop="price" content="10.0">
             R$ 10,00
          </div>
          <!-- /.product_price -->
          <p class="product-name" itemprop="name">Prod Kelly 01</p>
       </div>
    </div>
<div>
<div>
```

css

```
    product-grid.third {
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: -60px;
    }

    .product-grid {
        margin: 0 0px 35px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .product-grid.third .product {
        width: 30%;
    }

    .product-grid .product {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 24%;
        margin: 20px 1px;
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .tag-price-home {
        width: 135px;
        height: 90px;
        background-color: #f81889;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 10px;
        right: -5px;
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
        font-family: 'Chalet-Tokyo', sans-serif;
    }

    .price {
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 36px;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    product-img {
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        max-height: 296px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
```

How can I do this? I tried add *position: absolute* and *z-index: 99!important* in child and *position:relative* in parent (see this answer [how to position two divs above each over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834831/how-to-position-two-divs-above-each-over)) but doesn't works.

Comment: remove `overflow:hidden` from `.product-grid .product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .product-grid .product {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 24%;
    margin: 20px 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Since the sticker has "position: absolute;", "overflow: hidden;" will not automatically extend the height of the parent element if it doesn't have height atribute, but it will cut off everything that's not inside of the element, same as if you would assing height: 200px; and overflow: hidden; and then put in a child that's 300px in height.

I've tried your code on jsfiddle and I removed "overflow: hidden;" from class the class above and it seems to be working like you want it to.

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/gLojqos2/