# CSS/JS Scroll a lower z-index div

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, z-index

I have a container with two divs overlapping inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834831/how-to-position-two-divs-above-each-over/1834868).

the lower z-index div has overflow-y scroll, and it can scroll but only while the mouse cursor is not in the bounds of a higher z-index div.

I would like to propagate the scroll till the lower z-index div in the stack...

how do you accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on the higher stacked element. It makes the element *transparent* to pointer events.
See [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on MDN.

If the higher element has children which you want to have pointer events on, you need to give each of those children: `pointer-events: all;` (or `auto` - default).