# CSS - how to stack two <div> elements on top of one another that resize together?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to stack two `<div>`components on top of one another that can also resize automatically according to the window size - this means that one of the two `<div>` will always be on top of the other.

I was wondering if this is possible, to have two different div components that are `position: relative` and automatically resize? I believe it is possible to do this with one `position: absolute` involved ([how to position two divs above each over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834831/how-to-position-two-divs-above-each-over/1834868)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stack a div on top of another you need to use position: absolute. However, you can then put them both in a containing div with position: relative.
To size relative to window size use vh and vw.

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 10vw;
  top: 25vh;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

.box-one {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-two {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-one"></div>
  <div class="box-two"></div>
</div>
```

vw and vh are length units representing 1% of the viewport size for viewport width (vw) and height (vh), respectively.

z-index specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

box-one (red) will stack on top of box-two (blue).
box-one & box-two will take up 80% of the container.

Position: absolute; The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

oh and if you are using react, change class to className

Comment: J Davies, thank you for your response!
I was wondering if this was possible: I will set box-one to be the same size as the container. Afterwards, I will position buttons in the box-one div using margin (I'm not sure this is the proper way to do this but the intention is to map a button always above a certain position on both the box-one div and the background div). I've set up my render to have <div (container)> which has <div (box-one)> inside, which has the exact location of <button> which is mapped using margin.

Comment: (cont) J Davies, so the margins that I set in the button css should apply to within the boundaries of the container & box div

Comment: You can use margin to position elements but its not a good idea in this case as the container changes size but (i assume) the buttons will have a fixed size so the ratio would change.
with position absolute or relative you can use css properties: top or bottom & left or right. e.g to put box-one in the bottom right corner: right:0; bottom: 0;
To make it horizontal center ADD to .container {  text-align: center; }. and change box-one to
.box-one {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 10%;
}

Comment: here is a demo you can play around with for practice
 [link](https://codepen.io/Dev_Josh/pen/NWNPbYx)